# Divergent $\epsilon - N$ Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let: $\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}}$

I'm having trouble proving this with an $\epsilon - N$ proof, I know that it's divergent but all of the divergence sequences that I have come across are bounded and just alternate between the upper and lower bounds and hence it was easy for me to choose $\epsilon$ and $ N$. But since this sequence isn't bounded above how would I go about proving this?

Comment: **Hint:**  Note that $\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}}>\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}.\ $ Then show that the sequence $\left(\sqrt{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ is unbounded:   $ (\forall\varepsilon>0)\; (\exists n_\varepsilon):\; (\forall n>n_\varepsilon) \;\; \sqrt{n}>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}.$

Comment: How exactly would you prove it? I've been at it for a good hour and I still can't solve it..

Comment: Take $n_{\varepsilon}=\left\lfloor{\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}}\right\rfloor +1.$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the sequence converges to $x\in \mathbb{R}$, select $\epsilon=1$, then by convergence, $\exists N, |x_n-x|<1, \forall n>N$.

Pick $n>max(N, (1+x)^2+1)$

$x_n=\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n}}>\sqrt{n}>1+x$, this leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n\geq \sqrt{n}$. Now for any given $\epsilon>0$ choose $N>\epsilon^2$ to Show the divergence